# Laravel 5 Plain Html MethodNotAllowedHttpException

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

Hello so I am trying to make an update form in Laravel using plain html. The url of my edit form is `http://localhost:8000/profile/sorxrob/edit`, `sorxrob` is the username. And the code in that url is:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" role="form" action="" method="POST">
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
<input name="_method" type="hidden" value="PATCH">
//more inputs
</form>
```

And in my controller named `AccountController`:

```
public function update(Request $request, $id)
{
    $account = Accounts::findOrFail($id);
    $input = $request->all();
    $account->fill($input)->save();
    return 'success';
}
```

And I am getting the error `MethodNotAllowedHttpException` when I click the update button. Is it because my action is equal to nothing? If yes, what is the correct way of routing there?

Answer (score 2):

This is due to your action url which is not correct routing url. Use the following

(1) First define a route in your route.php file

```
Route::post('profile/{username}/edit', array('as' => 'profile.update', 'uses' => 'AccountController@update'));
```

(2) Change your action attribute from your form tag

```
action="{{ URL::route('profile.update', [$username]) }}"
```

here $username variable will be passed from your  AccountController@edit method.